# How to input value data export display to code preview & file?

Tags: javascript

I want to use `.js` to make input form export to `.html` code preview & file, but input value cant display to 'id' elememt. please help me what can edit this code problems?

html code:

```
<div>
<input type="text" id='btn' disable='disable' value="Content">
</div>
<div id='content'></div>
<div id='main'>
<textarea id='code'></textare>
</div>
<a href="#" id="downloadLink">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Js code:( Input value)

```
var oBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
var oTi = document.getElementById('content');
var oCode = document.getElementById('code')

    if ('oninput' in oBtn) {
      oBtn.addEventListener("input", getWord, false);
    } else {
      oBtn.onpropertychange = getWord;
    }

function getWord() {
   oTi.innerHTML = oBtn.value;
   oCode.innerHTML = oTi.value;
    }
```

JS code: (export .html)

```
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click();
}

var fileName =  'tags.html';
```